# Using mixed case shortened URLs

Tags: uri

I have a content type **Advert**, which have **image** and **URL** fields and I put it in a block to place it on the page.

All works fine EXCEPT when the advertiser provides a mixed case `Bit.ly` shortened link to their site, Drupal is converting it to lower case but `Bit.ly` is case sensitive and either does not find the link at all or it redirect to another . How can I force Drupal to retain the mixed case URL, at least for external URLs? The `Bit.ly` link is important as the advertiser uses it to track ad clicks and hence the performance of the advert on our site

Comment: Where / how are you storing the link?

Comment: you can do it simply add css property on specific add css property text-transformation first letter is capital

Comment: I store it as a URL field in the content type.

I would not know where to start to add the css property I am afraid. The configuration of the site is entirely through module configuration and no bespoke code. I did not create the template although I have on occasions added the odd line at the end of the css files.

The llink format is usually of the form: http://bit.ly/1jcmXY8 but the caps can be anywhere in the final part of the string.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think text transformation would do it as I want to retain the capitalisation not shift it all to upper or lower case.

Comment: CSS text transformation has nothing to do with case sensitivity of a URL. It's for display purposes only, the browser will still follow the link in the HTML. @M-dash When you say "Drupal is converting it to lower case", what do you mean? When is it doing that?

Comment: The URL Field (URL field module) is saved in mixed case, that is ok. But when it is rendered the href= is all lower case. In the block in Views the formatter selected is Link, the only option.

See http://vehicle-electronics.biz - the header banner is the current issue (but until I resolve it I am not using the shortened mixed-case tracking URL)

Somewhere in between it gets converted to all lowercase

Comment: I would report that as a bug to the Views module (or whatever module provides the link handler). Unless you've specifically told it to change the case, it definitely shouldn't be doing so

Answer (score 0):

Doh, what a dummy! I missed an option in rewrite results on the image field to set output as link with no transform!

Thanks everybody.